# How do elemental procs work in Riptide?

Tags: dead-island-riptide

In Dead Island (1), every time that you landed a critical hit with an elementally modified weapon on an enemy, the elemental effect would be applied. Among the elemental effects, there are fire, shock, impact, poison, fire, and bleeding.

In Dead Island Riptide, this is certainly not the case. It seems that when that an elemental effect is applied and when that you critical hit, are independent variables. What's the algorithm for when the elemental effect is applied? Secondly, how can the elemental proc rate be improved?

Comment: This question is confounded by the fact that certain weapon mods only apply if the target is grounded or dies on the last hit. This may have led to the impression that crits are independent from procs. If the assumption made in my question is wrong (that they are independent), then the question should be: do certain weapon mods only work on targets that are (not) in a specific condition? If so, which?